# Simple Flask app works locally, but crash when I deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

It's a simple flask app here is the code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import InviteForm
import requests
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]

@app.route("/home")
def landing_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/invite", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def invite():
    form = InviteForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        invite_slack_result = invite_to_slack(form.email.data)
        print(invite_slack_result)
        if invite_slack_result["ok"]:
            flash('Invite send at {}'.format(form.email.data, 'success'))
        else:
            flash(invite_slack_result)
        return redirect(url_for('landing_page'))
    return render_template('invite.html', title='Invite', form=form)

def invite_to_slack(user_email):
    slack_request = 'https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token='
    slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
    user_email = '&email=' + str(user_email)
    url = slack_request.strip() + slack_token.strip() + user_email.strip()
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    print(data["ok"])
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried all guides out there but when I deploy to heroku app always crash.
Here is the log:

```sh
›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.19.3 to 7.24.1
2019-05-03T09:55:43.480413+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:55:43.641038+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:55:43.641038+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:55:43.480413+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:56:44.939393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=fast-temple-32581.herokuapp.com request_id=14db9962-9b66-4bf3-8745-ef09b221f655 fwd="46.176.119.138" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-03T09:56:46.072393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-temple-32581.herokuapp.com request_id=44c5fe2b-2375-4139-955b-e7493847bf60 fwd="46.176.119.138" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-03T09:58:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:59:02.166369+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:59:02.166369+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 80d67888 by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:59:02.179942+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user myemail@gmail.com
2019-05-03T09:59:06.601864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`
2019-05-03T09:59:09.154085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-03T09:59:09.159463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-03T09:59:09.131387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-05-03T09:59:08.970428+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-05-03T09:59:08.971230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:38229 (4)
2019-05-03T09:59:08.977780+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-05-03T09:59:08.985422+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992316+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992320+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992325+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992326+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992328+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992330+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992332+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992333+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992335+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992339+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992340+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992342+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992344+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992345+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992385+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run'
2019-05-03T09:59:08.992603+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-05-03T09:59:09.045407+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-05-03T09:59:09.045727+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-05-03T09:59:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-05-03T09:59:12.048363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`
2019-05-03T09:59:14.458234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-03T09:59:14.447613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-05-03T09:59:14.324923+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-05-03T09:59:14.325632+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14930 (4)
2019-05-03T09:59:14.325973+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-05-03T09:59:14.331737+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337117+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337120+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337123+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337124+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337126+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337128+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337129+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337131+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337133+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337135+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337136+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337138+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337140+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337141+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337143+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337145+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337146+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run'
2019-05-03T09:59:14.337279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-05-03T09:59:14.365569+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-05-03T09:59:14.365656+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-03 09:59:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-05-03T09:59:23.531289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-temple-32581.herokuapp.com request_id=23abb9dc-bfc5-4e3f-8460-3ac6367bc50c fwd="46.176.119.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-03T09:59:25.345486+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-temple-32581.herokuapp.com request_id=ab5c577d-1ce1-4eb1-a2de-94840c8f13e5 fwd="46.176.119.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried almost guides/videos/tutorials but I always get the same problem, I don't know what's wrong and at this point I can't even guess

[Here is thepastebin link to the error log](https://pastebin.com/QJJuAesX)

[Here is the full project on github](https://github.com/Belonias/psgSlackInvite/blob/master/psgSlackInvite.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some information in the Heroku crash log:

> 2019-05-03T09:59:06.601864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`
>   ......
>   2019-05-03T09:59:08.992345+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
>   2019-05-03T09:59:08.992385+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run'

**Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`**
It seems that you didn't set the right WSGI application for gunicorn

Add a Procfile file at project root directory,
the content of this file is :

```
web: gunicorn psgSlackInvite:app
```

you project's wsgi application is "app" in the module "psgSlackInvite"

Comment: Yes you are right, seem the problem gone away, thank you very much for your time.